# How to compare two arrays in my case

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to compare the array and values

I have something like

```
$values = array(1,5,9);
$array = array(1,3,5,7,9);
```

I want to get if 1,5,9 is within `$array`

so I did

```
foreach($values as $value) {
    if(in_array($value, $array)){
       echo "found";
    }else{
       //i also need get 3 and 7 from `$array` because they are not in values array
       //How do I do this?
    }
}
```

However, I also need get 3 and 7 from `$array` because they are not in values array. Is there anyways to do this? Thanks.

Comment: `array_diff()` is the buit-in function for this. http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Comment: You mean like [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)?

Comment: @MarkBaker We sort of need a "common array operations" reference question. I can't find any good dupes for this.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it in that foreach, however, have you considered something like this:

```
$values = array(1,5,9);
$array = array(1,3,5,7,9);

foreach($values as $value) {
    if(in_array($value, $array)){
       echo "found";
    }
}

//check numbers that are not in array
$diff = array_diff($array, $values);
print_r($diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe searching in the target array

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    if(in_array($value, $values)){
       echo "found: ".$value;
    }else{
       echo "not found: ".$value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just store them in a new array:

```
$valuesNotInArray = array();

foreach($values as $value) {
if(in_array($value, $array)){
   echo "found";
}else{
   //i also need get 3 and 7 from `$array` because they are not in values array
   //How do I do this?
   array_push($valuesNotInArray, $value);
}
```

And then do whatever you want with the elements in $valuesNotInArray.

Or echo them out:

```
foreach($values as $value) {
if(in_array($value, $array)){
   echo "found";
}else{
   //i also need get 3 and 7 from `$array` because they are not in values array
   //How do I do this?
   echo $value;
}
```

Comment: they will only cycle through the values array with your answer and it wont push his $array values that are not in $values array. You would need to inverse the foreach like Arnaldo does in his answer.